# Errors Writing CSVs with Python

Tags: python, csv, file-io, numpy

I'm encountering errors in the .csv files that I'm writing with python (the necessary format because I'm on a team which depends on .csvs).  In a non-patterned way, there are errors creeping up across hundreds of 1g files.  For example, an extra 10 columns for only 1 row, an extra row with eroneous inputs, certain rows missing ~10 colums.  I have re-run the same script twice, and on the second run the errors are absent.  I need a way to ensure that these files are being written properly.  Here is the code I'm using (I know it isn't the most efficient, but I knew how to do it in this fashion, and I wanted to post it how I was doing it).

```
# Sample inputs, representative of the actual data I'm working with.  
output = np.zeros([40000, 1000]) # for example
iso3 = 'ALB'
sex = 'M'
year = np.ones(40000)
post_env = np.repeat(10, 40000)
post_cause = np.repeat('a', 40000)
post_pop = np.repeat(100, 40000)
outsheet = np.zeros([output.shape[0], output.shape[1]+7], dtype='|S20')
outsheet[:, 0] = iso3
outsheet[:, 1] = sex
outsheet[:, 2] = np.array(post_year, dtype='|S20')
outsheet[:, 3] = np.array(post_age, dtype='|S20')
outsheet[:, 4] = np.array(post_cause, dtype='|S20')
outsheet[:, 5] = np.array(post_env, dtype='|S20')
outsheet[:, 6] = np.array(post_pop, dtype='|S20')
outsheet[:, 7:] = np.array(output, dtype='|S20')

outsheet[outsheet=='nan'] = '.'
first_row = ['draw' + str(i) for i in range(output.shape[1])]
first_row.insert(0, 'population')
first_row.insert(0, 'envelope')
first_row.insert(0, 'cause')
first_row.insert(0, 'age')
first_row.insert(0, 'year')
first_row.insert(0, 'sex')
first_row.insert(0, 'iso3')
outfile = open('filename', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(first_row)
writer.writerows(outsheet)
outfile.close()
```

Errors have even included random numeric values in the first column (which should all be 'ALB'), an extra set of rows for an observation, and an observation missing columns (post-writing).

Comment: Not that it should matter, but python version, distribution and OS?

Comment: Have you tried `numpy.savetxt`?

Comment: I'm using /epd-7.0-2/ on a cluster system.  I have not tried numpy.savetxt, but would appreciate it if you could explain how to write the title row, and then the following rows using the program.

Comment: @mike: `with open('filename', 'w') as f: \n f.write(header) \n np.savetxt(f, outsheet, fmt="%.2g", delimiter=", ")`

Answer (score 3):

As an aside, using xrange instead of range is usually faster.

Are you absolutely certain that the memory and and disk on the machine that runs the job are good? Since your data ranges into the hundreds of gigabytes, it's not out of the question that you're seeing hardware-based corruption. Even if the machine seems to run stably without crashing, single-bit memory errors are pretty common at these data densities. If any of the hardware is marginal, this is the sort of behavior I'd expect.

Are your disks running a checksummed raided format? (ZFS is my favorite) Are you using ECC memory? Do you see more errors when it's hot during the day? Do you see these errors on the machine itself, or after transferring over a network?

How long does your operation take to run? Do you see more errors towards the end?

Comment: Hmmm... It's both comforting and discomforting to hear that it might be a machinery error.  I unfortunately don't know much about the system I'm running on.  The scripts take about 1-1.5 hours to run, and only produce identifiable results (write files) at the end of the script.  Note, I'm running hundreds in parallel on a cluster system, which might also conflate the potential for error.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: With data that big, network transport errors are a likely culprit if you're reading the files directly. If you're archiving, compressing, and checksumming, that will help.

Comment: If the machine that's running these scripts is a proper server, it probably has ECC memory. If it's a desktop, or something that's been repurposed to be a server, it probably doesn't. ECC will keep cosmic rays at bay, but it won't really help if any other part of the chain is bad.

Comment: As a first order solution, you might try running memtest86 on the machine if you can get physical access to it.

Comment: Thanks for the tips -- could you say a bit more about archiving, compressing, and checksumming (ie, how I would use these, what it might accomplish in this context)?

Comment: If your corruption is coming from the network, if you compress the files to a tar.gz and then take the md5 of them, when they arrive on your end, you can verify the md5 to make sure it's correct. If it's not, re-transfer the file. Compression is likely to be a very big win on this sort of file, into the bargain.